# Вывод избранных товаров на странице

Tags: php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]В общем сейчас на сайте реализована кнопка добавления и удаления из избранного, теперь необходимо вывести избранные товары на странице.У не авторизованных пользователей ID избранных товаров хранятся в сессиях,а у авторизованных хранятся в бд и в сессии.Сейчас стоит задача вывести эти товары на странице Избранных. Вот как мне обрисовал план действий разработчик у которого я в подчинении :
нужно получить массив id из сессии, сделать мерж с массивом id из БД. и этот массив id скормить в селект на товары. полученные полные данные скормить в catalog-smalldescription.php , после чего делай инклюд catalog-smalldescription.php в цикле. всё по аналогии с каталогом

Объясните пожалуйста более подробно(для тупых),что нужно сделать и желательно с примерами .Камнями не кидайте ,у меня базовые знания в PHP и работаю только 3 неделю программистом

Я сделал вот такую хрень, но боюсь кроме ,как хренью этот код и не назовешь.

```
$favoriteDb = mysqli_query(DB::db(), "SELECT * FROM users_goods")->fetch_assoc();
$favoriteSes[] = $_SESSION['favorite'];
$result = array_merge($favoriteSes,$favoriteDb);
var_dump($result);
```

//во вложении результат моего мега МЕРЖА

Answer (score 0):

Раз уж у вас в `$_SESSION['favorite']` ид товаров являются ключами массива, то просто суйте в этот массив данные из бд

```
$favoriteSes = $_SESSION['favorite'];    // не надо здесь "$favoriteSes[] ="
foreach ($favoriteDb as $row) {
    $favoriteSes[$row['GOOD_ID']] = 1;
}
```

Ну и затем его в селект:

```
$query = 'SELECT ... WHERE id IN ('.implode(', ', array_keys($favoriteSes)).')';
```

Answer (score 0):

Как тогда человек убирает товар из избранных?

Я бы предложил `234444 => -1`.

Тогда простой `array_merge` не подойдет, нужно делать 2 цикла:

- добавить из базы, исключая удаленные
- добавить добавленные из сессии

Потом запрос.